# Do any GPUs support fine grain system SVM?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

[OpenCL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.0-openclc.pdf) introduced `Shared Virtual Memory (SVM)`, allowing virtual memory addresses to be shared between hosts and devices.

There are a number of different SVM capabilities, see this extract from `cl.h`:

```
/* cl_device_svm_capabilities */
#define CL_DEVICE_SVM_COARSE_GRAIN_BUFFER           (1 << 0)
#define CL_DEVICE_SVM_FINE_GRAIN_BUFFER             (1 << 1)
#define CL_DEVICE_SVM_FINE_GRAIN_SYSTEM             (1 << 2)
#define CL_DEVICE_SVM_ATOMICS                       (1 << 3)
```

According to [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-20-shared-virtual-memory-overview) from Intel, the `CL_DEVICE_SVM_FINE_GRAIN_SYSTEM` capability means that an OpenCL device can share an operating systems' address space, *without* creating an SVM buffer for it.

Supporting fine grained SVM with a CPU device should be relatively simple. My (6th gen, Skylake) system reports that it supports `CL_DEVICE_SVM_FINE_GRAIN_SYSTEM` using the Intel `Experimental OpenCL 2.1 CPU Only Platform`. However, the Skylake GPU and CPU do *not* support `CL_DEVICE_SVM_FINE_GRAIN_SYSTEM` using the normal `Intel(R) OpenCL` platform.

I can imagine that it is very hard (if not impossible!) for a GPU on a graphics card to support fine grained SVM. However, it should be possible for a GPU on an APU, such as an `Intel i7` or an `AMD A10` to support it.

Do any GPUs support fine grained system `Shared Virtual Memory`?

Comment: This topic has been discussed in an [Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/opencl/topic/541722) couple years back. The guy from Intel says he had not seen any product with fine grain system SVM. The lack of information on the web about the system SVM shows there are no systems with this capability as of now.

Comment: I believe it is more about OS support than HW, as Intel HW does support Fine Grain buffers.

Comment: @Elalfer I believe that it is a combination of HW and driver support. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL#OpenCL_2.1_support) Intel 7th gen Kaby Lake processors support OpenCL 2.1. However, I don't know whether they (or the 8th gen Kaby Lake X and Coffee Lake APUs) support fine grained system SVM?

Comment: KBL should support FG SVM as far as I know (I even tested some of the stuff before).